# Glide loaded image resets when back button clicked

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am loading image with glide.
but problem is,when we press back button loaded image clear from the view .I am facing this issue wherever I load image either on activity image view or in recyclerview.

I am loading image with

```
GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(mToolbarAvatar);
```

Comment: did you solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines in your code

```
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```

Comment: but I want to cache image also

Comment: Try with: .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)

Comment: Please refer: [Caching in Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()                       
                  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE) // because file name is always same
                  .skipMemoryCache(true);

 Glide.with(this)
           .load(photoUrl)
           .apply(requestOptions)
           .into(profile_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using diskCacheStrategy.ALL.

```
  Glide.with(Activity.this)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                .load(URL)
                .centerCrop()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```